# Regex: How to exclude one word and one character?

Tags: regex, perl, sitescope

I'm working with the Dynamic Disk Monitor in SiteScope and I need a regex that exclude the word "Harddisk" and the character "D".

So far, I found this:

```
^(?!.*Harddisk).*/percent full
```

How do I add the part for the exclusion of "D" in the same expression? I tried this and didn't work:

```
^(?!.*Harddisk|^D).*/percent full
```

**More details:**

This expression brings the percent full of all the Disks that the server has:

```
/.*/percent full/
```

This exclude all the disk that its name start with "Harddisk":

```
/^(?!.*Harddisk).*/percent full/
```

What I need is to improve the last expression for exclude all the "Hard Disk" and besides, the disk "D".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards, Estrella.

Comment: Did you try `^(?!.*Harddisk|D)`?

Comment: It was the first thing that I tried :(

Comment: I tried it (`$my_var =~ /^(?!.*Harddisk|D)/`) and it worked OK for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker helped me and found the answer and I wanted to share it with you:

```
/^(?!.*[E])^(?!.*(HarddiskVolume)).*/percent full/
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks to everyone who answered this!

-Estrella

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(?>[^HD/]++|\BH|H(?!arddisk)|/(?!percent full))+/percent full
```

(Don't forget to escape the slash if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if !/(?=.*\bHarddisk\b)(?=.*\bD\b)/;
}

__DATA__
Harddisk A
disk D
Harddisk D
```

Output:

```
Harddisk A
disk D
```

The expression evaluated by `if` has the following form: `!(x and y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
m{/percent full} && !/\bHarddisk\b/ && !/D/
```